# You do not have permission to call getUserCache

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, authorization, google-apps-script-addon

An exception of type 'You do not have permission to call getUserCache' is raised when our add-on activates itself.

**Scenario**

- Install the add-on
- A custom menu is well displayed
- Open a new Spreadsheet

**Real**

- Menu does not build anymore

**Expected**

- Menu is well displayed on this new spreadsheet

An exception is thrown is the console: 'Google Apps Script: You do not have permission to call getUserCache'

Code is as the following:

```
    public onOpen(e): void {
        //
        // CacheService.getUserCache() to check something
        // menu build statements based on a previous value retrieved from this cache service call

    }
```

Comment: Use `ScriptCache`? In AuthMode:None, you can't access user-cache

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment we solve it by updating the menu based on this CacheService response.